# Someone can recover my Gmail account through answering account creation date

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

There is a guy who can recover and log into my Gmail account just by answering when my account was created.(idk how he guessed my account creation date)

Even after adding recovery emails and phone and etc he still can access and delete all my recovery.

Any solution how can I secure my account completely and delete that recovery question of asking "account creation date" by Google?

Comment: Did you change your password?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to activate 2 step verification?

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839